# Serving json from a file express js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, express

Newbie to express, I have a folder that has a db.json file and it gets replaced with a new db.json every 11 seceonds. What is the best way to let express.js serve it so that new content shows on api call? This is what I have so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/items', (req, res) => {
  let dbPath = require('./data/db.json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(dbPath));

});
```

db.json looks something like this

```
[{"recordType": "E90", "count": "55", "space": "4" },
{"recordType": "A48", "count": "40", "space": "5" }, ....]
```

Problem: I'm not seeing the updated value next time I make the api call.

Comment: That should work for you, is it not?

Comment: why is that JSON file being replaced every 11 seconds?

Comment: The best way is to not load a file on every route request at all. Disk reads/writes are usually slow. You would be better off using a database like Redis / MongoDB (depending on your needs). Databases like Redis or MongoDB cache frequently used assets in the RAM, hence you can expect it to be much faster.

Comment: @kentor express sendFile already use streams to transfer files

Comment: This setup didn't work. So having database is the only option?

Comment: @Jhecht Working with a legacy system. Just exploring what can be done to make it available to client side without the need of database.

Comment: @jeesan485 I can't figure out the problem, you mean that you are getting an error when you try to call `/api/items` route **OR** you can't download the file ?

Comment: @YouneL I'm not seeing the updated value next time I make the api call.

Comment: @jeesan485 very well could be caching. (assuming you fixed the fact that you're just returning the filepath atm)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/api/items', (req, res) => {

    fs.readFile('./data/db.json', (err, json) => {
        let obj = JSON.parse(json);
        res.json(obj);
    });

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can the content be sent in any way instead of the file?

Comment: Yes you can in this case you may want to use `JSON.parse`, I updated my answer for you

Comment: This is working only thing I added "__dirname" and it worked.