# how to invoke my .json file which is present in my local system into a http link?

Tags: angularjs

CONTROLLER.JSON file

```
var app=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
app.controller('people', function($scope, $http){$http.get('C:\Users\test1\src\database.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.persons = response.records; }); });
```

The error that I receive is -

> zone.js:2019 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file://C:/Users1srcdatabase.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: You can't you need a Web Server to serve your file as you notice your request says "http.get" therefore you need a Web Server to serve your file file through an http protocol. If not mistaken also for security reasons Javascript can't look into your local files. It is beyond its capacity

Comment: ok.. so what should I have to do? I am learning angular currently and I can't seem to find a solution for this!

Comment: Install NodeJs and use Express to server your file, I guess it will be the simplest quickest way. If you are using Windows then you may install IIS that is also a simple Web Server to use you will need to install asp.net

Comment: Node js is installed already..  are you suggesting me to call "$ npm install express --save" ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539747/1959948

Comment: if I do that, I am receiving an error like-
 - ReferenceError: fs is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (controller.js:4) 
indicating the fs.readfile line!